# Cloud function failed with exception: Internal, no code in Flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have very simple code to just test Cloud Functions in my Flutter app together with Firestore Emulator.
My Flutter code looks like this

```
 CloudFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator(origin: 'http://localhost:5005');
final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
  functionName: 'addNumbers',
);
dynamic resp = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{});
```

my very basic function looks like this:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addNumbers = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
  return true;
});
```

and I get an error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(functionsError, Cloud function failed with exception., {code: INTERNAL, details: null, message: INTERNAL})
E/flutter (31009): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
E/flutter (31009): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:33)
E/flutter (31009): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31009): #2      MethodChannelCloudFunctions.callCloudFunction (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel_cloud_functions.dart:43:15)
E/flutter (31009): #3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:33:12)
```

Any ideas what might be the reason? There is no code or suggestion what might have happened. I've added `Cloud Functions` dependency to `build.gradle`, as well as `google-services.json`

Edit:
Looks like the issue is with the emulator. I've deployed function to the server. Fixed the issues (wrong return type) and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The error is not with the emulator actually :

you are calling http://**localhost**:5005
when you run it in the emulator you have to change it to : **10.0.2.2** , so you can access localhost through emulator hope that helps .

10.0.2.2 = localhost

Comment: if that helps please approve the answer , so the commnuity can relate to the error